Command history details in zsh, how to see current command. Details maybe arising from abandoned history editing
I have my own cross machine bash/zsh sqlite database for command history that has many years of data compactly and also allows thinning, selective deletes etc. I have used it far longer with bash than zsh (under various macOS).
Recently I have noticed it can sometime log a whole host of commands rather than just one command. I have dug back through my code and it arises from my use in zsh of getting the text of current command from
history -t '%dz%m %T' -1

The z is just a literal to record the command was processed by zsh, it would be b for bash for which I employ a simpler but similar history command.
This history command seems problematic as detailed below, raising a number of detail questions in turn.
Main question: what is a better way of getting the equivalent command text as expanded and time stamped as a source in my sql scripts?
I've also spotted * in the history info; found that relates to command modification/editing. Like others I can't really see why that would be useful and so am looking at adding to .inputrc line (for zsh): set revert-all-at-newline on
Here is some recent output from history -t '%dz%m %T' -1
 1889  20z10 11:53:34  cat ~/.inputrc
 1890* 20z10 11:55:03  set
 1891* 20z10 11:57:04  echo abc
 1892* 20z10 11:57:12  cat ~/.zshrc
 1893* 20z10 11:57:22  hl -d
 1894* 20z10 12:07:49  man history
 1895* 20z10 12:07:55  help history
 1896* 20z10 12:08:08  history -?
 1897* 20z10 12:08:15  history -help
 1898* 20z10 12:08:20  history --help
 1899* 20z10 12:08:32  history

A few questions arise:

I thought the last -1 in the command meant give me 1 line.
What does the * list mean?
Where could I find that info in manuals or    help?? (you can see
some of my attempts)
How would I have got just the one line?
What terminates this *-ing of commands

There are a few terminals windows running and they are all sharing one zsh history...
Now if we compare that "history" with basic output from my own sql logs (note my sql exit timestamps are GMT and differ 1 hour from the locale time):
124241  2024-10-20 10:53:34  ttys004   1889  20z10 11:53:34  cat ~/.inputrc
124242  2024-10-20 10:55:03  ttys003   1816  20z10 11:55:03  set
124243  2024-10-20 10:57:04  ttys000   1781  20z10 11:57:04  echo abc
124244  2024-10-20 10:57:12  ttys000   1782  20z10 11:57:12  cat ~/.zshrc
124245  2024-10-20 11:07:52  ttys003   1820  20z10 12:07:49  man history
124246  2024-10-20 11:07:55  ttys003   1821  20z10 12:07:55  FAIL 127 help history
124247  2024-10-20 11:08:08  ttys003   1822  20z10 12:08:08  FAIL 1 history -?
124248  2024-10-20 11:08:15  ttys003   1823  20z10 12:08:15  FAIL 1 history -help
124249  2024-10-20 11:08:20  ttys003   1824  20z10 12:08:20  FAIL 1 history --help
124250  2024-10-20 11:08:32  ttys003   1825  20z10 12:08:32  history
124251  2024-10-20 11:08:43  ttys003   1826  20z10 12:08:43  history -t '%dz%m %T' -1
------  -------------------  -------  ---------------------------------------------------
id      time_exited          tty       cmd#  date time issued  history_command...........

NOTES
The command numbers created in zsh seem wrong, how did it get that given different terminals were at different command numbers (as per my sql log).
Some command number are missing in sql log, this is because I do not log interaction with my own log (the hl -d command), nor do I log repeated commands etc.
Are the 1890* - 1899* numbers in zsh history a bug in zsh or is there a good, opaque, reason?
Looking back in zsh previous commands with up-arrow for the * effect: I suspect it is all complicated by when zsh decides to write away history to file. I get to see what seem inconsistent things at different terminals with various timings and swapping back and forth.
Do you see this?
I do not have any AFAIK significant history settings active, just sizes of logs. Logging is all to one file, well it WAS> I'll change that to per terminal as it is how I originally worked for years in bash and does help me since I leave different sessions set up for different tasks, so it helps me to have distinct zsh histories.
To test I'd suggest having open 2 or more terminal zsh sessions.
Make sure current command numbers differ between your sessions, maybe by issuing a bunch of no impact commands in one place.

pico someTemp file.
Leave that open Go to another term window/session
and issue:
ls
echo abc
echo def
Use command editing to up arrow twice to show
the echo abc, append 123, then move away by up arrow again and issue
the ls
Check fc -l -1 or history -1
Back to the pico session, ^X
exit that.
Check fc -l -1 or history -1


The docs at man zshbuiltins and man zshoptions have some more info. I only get a single row of output with fc -l -1, but I don't have any of the history-related options set. You might see what happens with an un-customized shell instance (e.g. one started with /usr/bin/env -i /bin/zsh -f).

I did scan man zshall for history references (which I believe includes your mentions) and it was just overload for me, way too much detail, options, interactions to take on board in just a few hours. Good idea to check a vanilla shell though!! Plus I think the docs did refer to a few arrays of command related strings that I could focus on...

Given that this may only arise where multiple term  sessions are open (e.g.maybe I have an edit remaining open in one while another term session is active adding a few new lines to history) then what would be a simplest method or steps to ensure a clean vanilla logging across such session? pushing a new new shared log file in each terminal  maybe? (though I have never gone near that sort of thing)

I haven't been able to replicate what you're seeing, so I don't know what options could help. Answers to this post indicate that setopt incappendhistory and setopt sharehistory might have an effect.
